# ssrs disable export button on single report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that we want users to be able to see but not download at all. I have seen options for disabling certain options server wide but nothing for a single report using ReportManager . Preferably the export button would simply not be there.

Comment: You can use JavaScript to disable export options partially. Check [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0c680c69-9f7d-42aa-a6b4-b1178eab8adf/limit-report-from-being-exported-to-excel?forum=sqlreportingservices).

Comment: so would i just pass in every export type one after another to disable them all, but it would retain the button?

Comment: This is the usage sample `RemoveOption("/ReportSamples/report1", "Excel");` The first param is the report path you want to disable. Note this is JS code.

Comment: If some body can read it they can retype it. User can take screen shot and prints. Why do you want to restrict user to view only?

Answer (score 0):

The Export button is a part of the Report Manager application. It is not a component of a report and so cannot be set or managed for an individual report.

In this situation one approach is to embed the report inside an application or web page using the ReportViewer control, where you have complete control over the surrounding application.

Alternatively, you can provide access to the report via [URL access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms152835%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), which will allow the Report Manager toolbar to be completely hidden by using the `rc:Toolbar=false` command.